# Fetching Alexa data

Tags: php, alexa-internet

How is it possible to get traffic data, sub domains data, country rank in percentage like in http://www.websiteoutlook.com/www.google.com?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**NB**: *This approach doesn't work anymore*. The endpoint simply returns "Ok", even for URLs which aren't assigned.

There is a free API (though I haven't been able to find any documentation for it anywhere).

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=%YOUR_URL%
```

You can also query for more data the following way:

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=%YOUR_URL%
```

All the letters in **dat** are the ones that determine which info you get. This dat string is the one I've been able to find which seems to have more options. Also, cli changes the output completely, this option makes it return an XML with quite a lot of information.

**EDIT**: This API is the one used by the Alexa toolbar.

Comment: Awesome... works well. Do you know if there's a way to get the per country rank though? Say I want to get my websites rank in Australia.

Comment: There isn't a way, since the toolbar doesn't need that information (it doesn't show it). In case it's necessary, you should consider the paid API.

Comment: I read that making lot of requests to this URL will give you "503" error..

Comment: I haven't verified it, but since they have a paid API, it's logical that they'd put some kind of throttling in this one, which isn't meant for general use, but for their toolbar.

Comment: +1 for the incredible free link.

Comment: It seems not working now.

Comment: @ZillGate I just used it and had no issues.

Comment: Anyone knows what's the limit to the number of requests?  It seems like it basically only provides the dmoz.org info, which I'm sure could be had from elsewhere.

Comment: @cnst it provides a bit more information. The relevant additional info is on <SD>. As for the limit of requests, I don't currently know, since, as stated, it's a "private" API.

Comment: It works great, thanks!  I've just used this API the other day, and there appears to be no limits (as long as you don't stuff Alexa with as many requests per second as it could possibly handle -- a small delay between the requests is all that's needed to have all of them return `200 OK`).

Comment: This API not working for now and return Okay!

Comment: @nabeghe i have the same response, is there a solution?

Comment: Where are the "dat" letters documented?

Answer (score 16):

A simple function to get the alexa rank

```
function alexa_rank($url){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=".$url);
    if(isset($xml->SD)):
        return $xml->SD->REACH->attributes();
    endif;
}
```

Works pretty well and free ;)

Comment: Perfect thanks! I just added this to return the number with thousands separator: return number_format(floatval($xml->SD->REACH->attributes()));

Answer (score 14):

you can use this too

```
<?php
$url="http://stackoverflow.com/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
$web=(string)$xml->SD[0]->attributes()->HOST;
echo $web." has Alexa Rank ".$rank;
?>
```

this will output it like

```
stackoverflow.com has Alexa Rank 55
```

Answer (score 5):

Alexa have an API [here](http://aws.amazon.com/awis/). It's not free, though.

Comment: Hi, yes I know about the AWIS, but I am just curious to know if there are any free services for same?

Comment: @Prakash I don't know, but very hardly I think. Gathering these statistics is expensive...

Comment: I also think such freebie don't exist; at least not for alexa detailed information.

Comment: It is free. "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=".$url

Comment: data.alexa.com not working to scripts anymore

Comment: @Ashraf see https://support.alexa.com/hc/en-us/articles/200450214-Is-Alexa-s-data-available-via-an-API-

Answer (score 3):

[SimilarWeb](http://www.similarweb.com) has an API that exposes its traffic and ranking data. They also provide engagement metrics, referrals and domain categorization APIs, among others, so maybe it'll be good for you.

**API** -  [developer.similarweb.com](http://developer.similarweb.com)

Comment: What about the pricing?

Answer (score 1):

By using 
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=%YOUR_URL% API you can have all data.

Comment: tutology returns 404 Not Found.

Comment: Here is a saved version: https://web.archive.org/web/20131127045346/http://tutology.net/category/how-php/get-alexa-rank-php-and-alexa-api

Answer (score 1):

Usage for [SimilarWeb](http://www.similarweb.com) [Traffic API](https://developer.similarweb.com/traffic_api):

```
function api_traffic (URL, KEY) {

  var apiurl = "http://api.similarweb.com/Site/"
  + URL
  + "/v2/EstimatedTraffic?Format=JSON&UserKey=";
  + "KEY";


var fetch_visitors = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiurl);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);

      var data = JSON.parse( fetch_visitors);
    return data.EstimatedVisitors;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.siteprice.org/api/ is the cheapest I think and easy to use.

```
$worthofwebsite= file_get_contents('http://www.siteprice.org/WorthApi.aspx?type=1&key=testkey&url=google.com'); 
echo "Website Worth: ".$worthofwebsite;
```