# how to extract ranking and reputation of a website from alexa?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-applications

For my project I need to extract the ranking of any website from alexa by giving the url of that website . How could I possibly do that with ruby on rails or simply with javascript  .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are scraping Alexa to get these informations, you're doing something illegal.

Alexa has an [API](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/awis/). And you have to pay to use it.

Comment: Could you name some of the top web applications that use alexa api .

Comment: You can see an example here http://startupmeme.com/amazon-sues-alexaholic-for-using-alexa-api/

Comment: Since summer 2015 Amazon gives 1000 cals a month for free.

Answer (score 1):

The questions was replied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676376/fetching-alexa-data)

The following query:
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=http://stackoverflow.com


returns:

```html
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="stackoverflow.com/" HOME="0" AID="Hrr2p1frEw10p/" IDN="stackoverflow.com/">
<SD>
<POPULARITY URL="stackoverflow.com/" TEXT="53" SOURCE="panel"/>
<REACH RANK="54"/>
<RANK DELTA="0"/>
<COUNTRY CODE="US" NAME="United States" RANK="38"/>
</SD>
</ALEXA>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way using this url

```
https://www.alexa.com/comparison?&sites=google.com&display=json&useCookie=false&windows[]=rank:1y
```

in the response you will find rank object that has 3 months stats you could use i hope this is helpful for someone

**Update:**
This isn't working anymore sadly